# I made animated wind but doesn't seem to be working with the particle system

Tags: animation

do I have to set which objects will be influenced by the wind force?
I made animated wind but  doesn't seem to be working.  (The fighters have 2 meshes- one is Hair Particle and Particle Emitter. Hair keeps the particles on the surface and defines the fighters bodies, while Emitter - makes particle flow along the characters move).

[image]

Comment: Yes. You have to tell blender what objects each force acts on.

Comment: @MartyFouts no, that isn’t true. You have to specifically tell blender to ONLY influence objects in a certain collection. Otherwise it will influence everything by default.

Comment: thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the wind near to your particle system and set the strength to e.g. 100. Then you will see a result.